# Examples that show that AC is not that natural

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I recently took a course in set theory and I was wondering the following:

Let's "accept" that the axioms of $ZF$ are all natural and close to our intuition. As we know, $ZF$ can neither prove $AC$ nor $\neg AC$. Of course almost everyone that works outside of set theory works in $ZFC$, but I have the impression that $AC$ is somehow not as natural as $ZF$ nor that close to our intuition. What I'd like to know is, if there are any examples that point out/ defend the impression I mentioned above.

PS: I know that this question is a little too broad, so If anyone can improve it, please edit it.

Comment: See [The Axiom of Choice](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/).

Comment: For a full book, see T.Jech, [The Axiom of Choice](https://books.google.it/books?id=HrbDAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: For history, see G.H.Moore, [Zermelo's Axiom of Choice: Its Origins, Development, and Influence](https://books.google.it/books?id=3RLGKcEjVIoC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: The problem that people forget is that the failure of choice is just as unnatural as choice. For starters, $\lnot\sf AC$ itself seems to be extremely counterintuitive. Secondly, there is almost a dichotomy between "this kind of weirdness" and "that kind of weirdness" (and sometimes a little bit of both). It's not choice which is to blame. Seriously.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you please expand on your last statement "It's not choice which is to blame" I didn't quite get that

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378211/what-are-some-unintuitive-consequences-if-we-assume-that-axiom-of-choice-is-wron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of arguments both for and against Choice. The general attitude in the anti-Choice direction seems generally to be that it leads to existence proofs for objects which cannot be "constructed in a natural way" - e.g. ZFC proves the existence of a non-measurable set, but we have many results coming from [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) saying that such a set cannot have a simple description (especially under [additional set-theoretic hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal)).

Note that there is a similar flavor here to [arguments in favor of constructive logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic). However, in my opinion this similarity is actually fairly superficial. Consider, for example, the following definition: "$x=0$ if $P$ is true, and $x=1$ otherwise" (where $P$ is some statement you don't know right now is true or false - say, the Riemann hypothesis). Then this is certainly not a constructively-acceptable definition in general. However, we can separate the weirdness of a mathematical object from the weirdness of our description of it - in this case, $x$ is really *not weird at all* (it's either $0$ or $1$) even though we've defined it in a weird way - and so we can accept its definition while maintaining a commitment to only "concrete" mathematical *objects*.

Interestingly, arguments in favor of constructive logic can be invoked either for *or* against AC:

- **Against**: To the extent to which we view the mathematical universe as a construction of the mind, how can we accept an axiom which yields the existence of objects we can't describe?
- **For**: When we assert that a collection of sets is nonempty, we need to have a *constructive proof* of this fact. But such a proof amounts exactly to a choice function for that family!

In my view, this supports my claim that these issues - "non-constructive principles" in set-theory versus logic - are genuinely different.

---

All this, though, is a bit vague. It's a good idea to get acquainted with the precise mathematical issues here - both with AC and without AC - in order to appreciate the debate going on.

[Herrlich's book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540309895) is a good introduction to what mathematics looks like both with and without choice. [Jech's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486466248), which was recommended in the comments, is also quite good, but focuses mostly on the very advanced material - namely, proofs of consistency (e.g. showing that ZF neither proves nor disproves AC) - and may not be a good starting point.